# how to move or copy work item under a team to another team within same project in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions, devops-services

Is there any way to move or copy a work item from one team to another team within same project in Azure Devops?
Anyone please help

Comment: just change the area path to the second team area path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the Area path to the new teams name as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can move the work items:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops

Or you can create a copy using export and import csv backlog:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops